# BFS not returning a path

Tags: java, algorithm, path-finding, breadth-first-search

I am trying to implement BFS on a 2d array given the start point and end point. I tried giving my function two points on the grid, but it returns an empty array meaning that there is no path.

Can someone please point where am I going wrong and if possible help me correct my error? Thanks.

```java
public Point[] bfs2(Point start, Point end) {
    boolean[][] visited = new boolean[50][50];
    for (int i = 0; i < visited.length; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < visited.length; j++)
            visited[i][j] = false;

    visited[start.getX()][start.getY()] = true;
    LinkedList<Point> path = new LinkedList<>();
    Queue<Point> q = new LinkedList<>();
    q.add(start);

    while (!q.isEmpty()) {
        Point next = q.remove(); //i think the error is here
        Point[] neighbours = next.getNeighbours();
        path.add(next);

        if (next.getX() == end.getX() && next.getY() == end.getY())
            break;
        else if (!visited[next.getX()][next.getY()]) {
            for (Point neighbour : neighbours) {
                if (!visited[neighbour.getX()][neighbour.getY()]) {
                    q.add(neighbour);
                }

                visited[neighbour.getX()][neighbour.getY()] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    Point current = path.removeLast();
    ArrayList<Point> v = new ArrayList<>();
    while (current.getX() != start.getX() || current.getY() != start.getY()) {
        v.add(current);
        current = path.removeLast();
    }

    return v.toArray(new Point[v.size()]);
}
```

EDIT:

```
        Point current=q.peek();
    ArrayList<Point> v=new ArrayList<>();
    if(start.getX()==end.getX() && start.getY()==end.getY()) return new Point[0];
    while(current.getX()!=start.getX() || current.getY()!=start.getY()){
        v.add(current);
        current=current.parent;
    }
    return v.toArray(new Point[v.size()]);
```

Comment: any reason for the last 7 lines of convoluted code instead of a simple `Collections.reverse(path);` ?

Comment: Please also post your definition of `Point`.  Better yet, make it an MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: (Initialising the elements of `visited` to `false` is redundant.)

Comment: Why is initialising elements of visited to false redundant?

Comment: Point is a class that store x y coordinates and has multiple methods, it would be tedious to post it

Comment: (If you want a user notified of a comment to one of her comments, put an `@` before her name (you will get suggestions).)

Comment: From [The Java® Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html): `10.3. Array Creation

An array is created by an array creation expression (§15.10.1) or…` `15.10.2. Run-Time Evaluation of Array Creation Expressions

…Otherwise, there is no array initializer, and:…Then, if a single DimExpr appears, a one-dimensional array is created of the specified length, and each component of the array is initialized to its default value (§4.12.5)` `4.12.5. Initial Values of Variables … For type boolean, the default value is false.
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue is that you're adding all the elements you remove from the queue to the path (I'm referring to the line containing `path.add(next);`).

Instead, you should keep track of the parent node from which you visited each node. When you find the end node, you can trace back your steps to the start node.

If you have exhausted all the nodes and you still haven't found the end node, you can then return an empty list.

Let me know if you need an [MCV example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and I'll add it.

**Later Edit:**

You need to add a Point parent field to your class, like this:

```
class Point {
    int x;
    int y;
    Point parent; // reference to the Point from which this Point was visited

    // constructors, getters, setters, etc.
}
```

Then you can change your BFS implementation to also set the parent for the current node when iterating through its neighbors. You must change the loop to something like this:

```
        for (Point neighbour : neighbours) {
            if (!visited[neighbour.getX()][neighbour.getY()]) {
                q.add(neighbour);
                visited[neighbour.getX()][neighbour.getY()] = true;
                neighbour.parent = next;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Apologies if my questions are vague and not complete, I just started using stack overflow today, not used to asking properly. My next question is how can I keep track of the parent, where in my code is the parent? I tried to keep track at first of evert next point and ended up with an array of 105+ items in the array.

Comment: You can define an matrix of ``Point``s to store the parent ``Point``, similar to the ``visited`` matrix you already used. When marking the next node as visited, you can also set its parent in the ``Point``s array.

Btw, is ``Point`` a class that you defined or the one defined in java.awt.Point?

Comment: I coded the Point class. Thanks for the response, however I still don't understand how to get the parent. Ok I make a Point array than how do i set the parent each parent? I really don't understand how the parent should be set. Thanks for your help

Comment: I understand now, we are just making it possible to retrace the steps to get the shortest path. @Nikopol do you mind checking my retracing code logic, the code is the updated post above (at the end)

Comment: The first problem with your code for tracing back your steps is your start point. Why are you initializing the ``current`` ``Point`` from the next element in the queue? You should be back tracing starting from the ``end`` ``Point`` that you have found.